# URL Rewrite Sharepoint Search issues

Tags: sharepoint, search, url-rewriting

I am developing a SharePoint Portal in Microsoft Sharepoint 2010.

The fact is that I activated URL Rewrite module on Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.

I am rewriting urls like this:

> English/News/3/Title+Of+The+News **into**
>   English/News.aspx?id=3&title=Title+Of+The+News

All works well, the problem is that when I activate Search features, its seems that SP is not indexing the rewritten urls.

It only indexes one time the URL : English/News.aspx, but will not index the rewritten URLs such as (that targets the same page):

- English/News/3/Title+Of+The+News
- English/News/4/News2

All the rewritten links are available from the home page and many other pagesof my site, so I do not understand why SP is not indexing that links.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found it out.
I needed to add a Crawl Rule that index complex urls in Sharepoint.

Can be found here:
http://www.venkat.org/2008/07/how-to-index-complex-url-in-moss.html